# Getting the caret position in a RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, caret

In a .NET 3.5 application, i want to get caret position in a `RichTextBox` control. The RTB is not XAML. Also, the RTB doesn't have `CaretPosition` property as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition.aspx
What is the simplest way using which i can get the caret position?

EDIT:
To be more specific i want to find out what is the position of the caret from the start of the line on which it is positioned. I can get the line number by using `GetLineFromCharIndex(rtb.SelectionStart)` but not the offset from the start of the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the position of the caret from the start of the current line I will try this:

```
Dim posInLine as Integer = rtb.SelectionStart - rtb.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()
```

Comment: To get the caret position in the text of all lines together use only  `Dim posInText as Integer = rtb.SelectionStart`